# Selenium: Can't locate element with wait timeout set

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

Thanks for your time. It's a bit long, really appreciated.

I couldn't locate the element. I tried setting wait, switch frame, executing js

Here is part of the HTML DOM after the page is fully loaded: (the DOM inside iframe is omitted now)

```
<body class="ng1 nu-theme-neutrino nu-light-theme nu-nav-style-standard nu-responsive-mini nu-responsive-small">
        <div id="display" class="flex-centered">
            <div class="loading flex-centered" style="min-height: 300px">
                <f-icon class="fa-loading icon-xl"></f-icon>
            </div>
        <iframe style="border: 0px; height: 100%; position: absolute; width: 100%;">#document</iframe>
<div class="prompt legacy-prompt">
        <div class="content">
                <div class="flex-column-centered">
                        <p>Enter your credentials</p>
                        <input id="user" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="button-actions">
                        <button class="primary" type="button">Login</button>
                        <button type="button">Close Window</button>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="/4517d062d20772b8f56b8a652474eaed/js/legacy_theme_setup.js"></script></body>
```

Here is what I want to achieve in python

```
ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#user")
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#user"}
```

Then I tried setting wait

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#user")))
#or
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#user")))
```

Both got the same output:

```
[22112:23972:0111/131341.033:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[22112:23972:0111/131341.033:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[22112:23972:0111/131341.034:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[22112:1616:0111/131341.059:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [13:13:41.059] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[22112:23972:0111/131341.131:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a.py", line 60, in <module>
    ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
  File "C:\Users\...\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException
```

It says time out, so it didn't find the element within the time limit(60s)

Then I tried locating the element in the browser js console, it succeeded.

```
document.getElementById('pass')
<input id=​"pass" type=​"password" placeholder=​"Password">​
document.getElementById('pass').value = '123456'
'123456'
```

[browser js console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDB8p.png)

So I tried executing js

```
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('pass').value = '123456'")
```

Still can't locate

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a.py", line 54, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('pass').value = '123456'")
...
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: 
    javascript error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
```

I also tried to locate the frame, it seems the frame was not loaded properly

DOM inside the iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* some style */
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; cursor: text; user-select: none;">
    <x-screen role="textbox" tabindex="-1">
        <div
            style="display: block; position: fixed; overflow: hidden; user-select: text; width: 342px; height: 864px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <x-fold style="display: block; margin-bottom: 0px;"></x-fold>
            <x-row>Server closed connection.</x-row>
            <x-fold style="display: block;"></x-fold>
        </div>
        <div style="visibility: hidden; height: 870px;"></div><textarea tabindex="-1" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
    </x-screen>
    <div class="cursor-node" focus="false" title="(0, 25)"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: -99px; display: block; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
    ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")))
    print("iframe", ele) 
#output: iframe True

    ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html")
    print("html", ele.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
#output: html <head></head><body></body>

    ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cursor-node")
#output:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.cursor-node"}

    ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pass")
#output: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#pass"}

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pass")
#output: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#pass"}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone for answering and trying to help me out!

I used

```
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```

to print and see what is selenium actually seeing, and I found it was another different page. Then I realized this is another browser tab.

So I think it's solved. Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at `switch_to_frame`, see:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see, there is no need to switch the frame since this element is out of it.
[image]

I couldn't validate my idea, since the HTML code you placed isn't interactable.

I've modified the HTML setting up a default value in this item and it's not giving the value, however, I'm able to get the position and others values from this web element. I would advise to remove the switch method and then double check.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
try:
    driver.get('C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\chrome-selenium-python\\index.html')
    time.sleep(2)  # Let the user actually see something!

    ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#user")
    ele.send_keys("Example")
    time.sleep(2)  
    print("Location", ele.location)
    print("Tag", ele.tag_name)
except Exception as a:
    print(a)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)                                 
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"id"))).send_keys('user')
```

Try for presence.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Why are you using `(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#id")` instead of `(By.ID,"id")`? Using `By.ID` when you are using an ID makes it easier to read.